# Preventing algorithm2e linebreaks

Tags: line-breaking, algorithm2e

I want to include inline code examples such as **if** *i < n* **then** *i++* and **else** *i--*. I'm using the following LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
Inline code examples such as \lIf{i < n}{i++} and \lElse{i--} but
line breaks are being injected.
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

> Inline code examples such as **if** *i < n* **then** *i++*;
>
> and **else** *i--*;
>
> but line breaks are being injected.

Rather than what I would expect:

> Inline code examples such as **if** *i < n* **then** *i++*; and **else** *i--*; but line breaks are being injected.

How do I prevent linebreaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is expected to use all [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) macros inside an `algorithm` environment to write pseudocode. If you want to use it inline in text, then you need to remove the insertion of `\par`, which most structural pseudocode statements issue.

Below I defined `\llIf` and `\llElse` which remove this line-break issuing via a scope-limiting `\let\par\relax`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\llIf}[2]{{\let\par\relax\lIf{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\llElse}[1]{{\let\par\relax\lElse{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Inline code examples such as \llIf{$i < n$}{$i{+}{+}$} and \llElse{$i{-}{-}$} without
line breaks being injected.
\end{document}
```

Both macros lack the formal definition (which includes comments), but those aren't needed in inline usage, I assume.

Finally, don't mix the use of [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) with `algorithm2e`. They are two separate packages and shouldn't be used together.